# Can I marry a Chinese citizen in Germany as Blue Card holder?

Tags: blue-card

I am Chinese citizen and blue card holder in Germany. My girl is Chinese citizen and now stays in China. I hope to marry my girlfriend, but our marriage is not legal in China.
Can I marry her in Germany with her holding travel visa to Germany and me holding a Blue Card in Germany?

Comment: Please clarify why such a marriage is not legal in China. Because your girlfriend is a Chinese resident? Germany will require an **Ehefähigkeitszeugnis** (proof that you are not married) for both of you, so some form of cooperation with the Chinese authorities is required.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Probably because OP is not a man, or underage in China (men can only marry at 22). But a clarification would be useful.

Comment: @xngtng A **Certificate of marital status** (Ehefähigkeitszeugnis) would still be needed. Persons can generally be married with 18. A special visa would be needed for the spouse: [Visa for a marriage in Germany - Berlin.de](https://www.berlin.de/einwanderung/en/entry/visa-procedure/longer-stays/artikel.1048636.en.php)

Comment: not "legal" or not "valid"?

Answer (score 1):

The rule in Germany is that a marriage must be legal according to German law, and according to the laws of the countries that both spouses are citizens of.

If you are both Chinese citizens, then the marriage must be legal according to Chinese law, or you can’t get married in Germany. However, a German Standesbeamter will be able to tell you exactly whether you can get married, and what you would have to do to get married-if not, they will know who to ask. No they will be happy to help you, because you make their job interesting.

Comment: Would Germany recognize a marriage between two Chinese women officiated and registered in, say, Canada, or an European country like Ireland or Iceland?

Comment: If the marriage is legal according to German law, it would be very unusual not to accept a Canadian marriage and declare it as valid in Germany. At that point they don’t care about legality in your birth country anymore. If it’s not legal according to German law, like if some country married a 12 year old and a 21 year old, that wouldn’t be accepted.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed so. Could the marriage be recognized even if at the time of marriage both spouses are resident of Germany? Then I guess OP could just take a trip to another country without residency requirement to get the marriage officiated.

Comment: Found this https://www.toytowngermany.com/forum/topic/168557-germans-getting-married-in-las-vegas It’s a German website and talks about Germans getting married in Las Vegas but I can’t see why it wouldn’t apply to Chinese citizens living in Germany. Yes, marriage in Las Vegas is recognised in Germany after a law change - apparently lots of people got married there “just for fun” and after the law change some were surprised to be legally married.